# Android drawable background doesn't show on devices

Tags: android, android-layout, background, textview, shapedrawable

I want to give to a TextView a background. This background (classement_background.xml) is a drawable located in res/drawable.

Here's its code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <shape
        android:shape="ring"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <gradient
            android:startColor="#ff648add"
            android:endColor="#ff3656dd"
            android:type="linear"
        />
    </shape>
```

In the render window of the layout file, my background is set. (Android studio)

But for some reason, this drawable is not there anymore on a genymotion emulator nor an actual device.

I've been trying quite a few things (like making sure it isn't the first element in the drawable folder), but I can't figure out what's going on. Any thoughts ?

Here's the code from the textview itself : `

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="E2"
    android:id="@+id/classement"
    android:layout_below="@+id/firstname"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="85dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/classement_background"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>`
```

Comment: please change code of your drawable xml. and there are lots of code available on internet.

Comment: You have a typo: classement_background in the TextView XML and the filename is classemment_background

Comment: The typo was only here, not on my actual program. It's edited. I don't see what is wrong with the drawable. I've seen a lot of time almost the same structure..

Answer (score 1):

Add the android:useLevel="false" attribute to your shape tag. My IDE didn't display your shape in its preview window until I added it.

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape):

> android:useLevel
>
> Boolean. "true" if this is used as a LevelListDrawable. This should normally be "false" or your shape may not appear.

Comment: Same thing that I said to nastya. The problem is from somewhere else, I'll check it out further.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set android:thickness for the shape. Maybe android doesn't provide a default thickness for the xml drawables.

Comment: still Didn't work. But I copied/pasted an exemple from the android developpers guide. And it still didn't work. So, I must have done something that doesn't allow those drawables to work right.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I will post something, that helped me.
My backgroung id 1920x1920 pixels and display 1920x1080, so different size shouldn't be the problem.

I suppose that you have your background putted in some resource "drawable" folder (for example in *drawable-hdpi*) in Eclipse IDE. I had that either and on real device (Sony Xperia Z2) I haven't seen nothing.

**Short answer:**

I had to add my desired backgroung to every single drawable folder - ***drawable-ldpi, drawable-xxhdpi,*** ...

---

After this strange operation Sony finally recognized my backroung and accepted it. :-)

I hope this will help somebody.